# What is loadNibNamed: method doing in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TabBarController" owner:self options:nil];
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
```

I know this two lines of codes define the root view of my App,
But I do not know how these two line achieve it.

Can anyone explain these two lines of codes separately? Especially the first line I do not know what it is actually doing in our view mechanism

Thank you

Comment: The AppDelegate is responsible for setting up the initial UI screen.  The above lines are essentially doing that.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the xib you are passing `self` as `owner` so any connections you make in the xib to `File's Owner` will be setting properties on the app delegate. Inside your xib named `TabBarController` you will most likely have a `UITabBarController` that is connected to `rootController` On the `File's Owner`.

So once the xib has loaded and made all of it's connections you will have a reference to the `tabBarController` via `-[AppDelegate rootController]`. Next up you grab the view from the `rootController` and stick it in the view hierarchy.

This code needs updating. Since iOS 4 `UIWindow` expects to have a `rootViewController` set by the end of this method - you should see a warning to this effect in the log output.

Answer (score -1):

**First of all. Both of those lines are wrong.**

### What they do?

1. Tell the Main Bundle to open .nib file (compiled .xib), build objects described inside of it and connect *File Owner* conenctions to the `self`. **Wrong:** This should be responsibility of `UIViewController` and is done **automatically** using initializer `initWithNibName:bundle:`.
2. Add view of the view controller to the single window. **Wrong:** You should assign the view controller as window's `rootViewController`.

### How to do it?

1. Create a subclass of `UIViewController`, probably named `MYTabBarController`.
2. Create XIB file named *MYTabBarController.xib* (the same as the class), where the File owner is `MYTabBarController`.
3. In your *App Delegate* initialize this view controller:

   ```
   MYTabBarController *rootController = [[MYTabBarController alloc] init];
   // In case your XIB has different name: -initWithNibName:@"xib name" bundle:nil
   ```
4. Assign the view controller to window. This single line internally loads the XIB and adds subview, just like you were trying to do.

   ```
   window.rootViewController = rootController;
   ```

#### More options?

In case you don't need to subclass the `UIViewController`, you can:

1. Create a XIB, where the *File Owner* is the `UIApplication` itself. File name is not important.
2. Here you create **window**, **root view controller** (e. g. `UITabBarController`) and some nested view controllers as you want.
3. Specify this XIB in Info.plist under the key “Main nib file base name” or `NSMainNibFile`. And it will be loaded before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called.

Comment: Loading from a xib like that isn't horribly wrong. Judging by the code this could be some very early iOS template code. Plus this is essentially how storyboards work now e.g. They load viewControllers, which moves you away from the `alloc/init` when using them.

Comment: @Paul.s Of course not horrible, it can be used when loading a VC from multiple XIBs as an advanced technique. But if someone is learnings iOS dev, it should be clearly stated, that this is not the right way of doing it. And with Storyboards you also never loads nibs manually.